# How can I search DNS records by registrant or admin contact info, email address for example?

Tags: dns, search

I'd like to search for all domain names administered by `jon.doe@example.com` for example.  Are there any search tools out there that allow such a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Websites like [http://www.domaintools.com](http://www.domaintools.com/) offer this type of Service. Where you can find the no.of domains associated to their email address. But its not a Free Service. And you should know atleast one domain owned by that person.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to this tool.  I was hoping for a free tool, but I'll give this a try next time it is needed